# How to paste computer name for a file path

Tags: r, path

I am working on a project between a laptop and a desktop computer. My work is synchronised via Dropbox. To call up a file, when I'm working on my laptop I have to do

```
load ("MylaptopNamePATH/Dropbox/Folder1/Folder2/Myfile.R")
```

And if I'm working on my desktop computer, I have to change the path to the main folder on my desktop computer like:

```
load ("MyOfficeComputerNamePATH/Dropbox/Folder1/Folder2/Myfile.R")
```

Creating an R project does not solve the problem as I have to call other files from many other projects. I am looking for a code that prints the name of the computer so that I don't have to write the name of the computer every time I change computers.

Comment: You could look into the `here` package. It solved similar issues for me once and for all....

Comment: Perhaps `Sys.info()["nodename"]` could help you (or `Sys.info()`).

Comment: Another option is to set a symlink to Dropbox on both machines in your project folder. For example run `file.symlink(from = 'MyLaptopNamePATH/Dropbox', to = 'dropbox')` on the laptop (do this only once), and do the same on the desktop with its path to dropbox. Then you can use the code `load(file.path(dropbox, 'Folder...etc'))` on both machines.

Comment: Thank you to all of you